# System.IO.IOException at TCP/IP Connection

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

i´m having a problem with my TCP/IP Server/Client Connection:

On server start:

```
    {
        serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ipServer), portServer); 
        serverSocket.Start();
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        try
        {

            while (true)
            {

                NetworkStream nwStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string getdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                getdata = getdata.Substring(0, getdata.Length);
                ServerTextTB.Text = getdata;

                string serverresponse = "Response";
                byte[] sendbuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverresponse);

                nwStream.Write(sendbuffer, 0, sendbuffer.Length);
                nwStream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
    }
```

When Client sends Message:

```
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        clientSocket.Connect(ipClient, portClient);
        nwStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clienttext);
        nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        nwStream.Flush();

        byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        nwStream.Read(inStream, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        MessageBox.Show(returndata);
        clientSocket.Close();
        clientTextTB.Clear();
    }
```

My problem is, that every time i try to send a message to the server i get a System.IO.IOException in line 62 (  nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize); ) in my on server start methode.

After removing the Try/catch i get the following error:

`System.IO.IOException: 'Von der Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten gelesen werden: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen.`'

Translating it into english would mean something like:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from transport connection : An existing connection was closed by host.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
Both, the server and the client run on the same computer

Greetings & thank you

Comment: You should check the return value of `nwStream.Read(...)`. It returns the number of bytes actually read, or 0 if the client has disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Your client closes after reading back the message from server, while the server continues the loop and blocks in "Read", waiting for a message from client. When client closes the connection, server gets an exception.

If you want to prevent this situation you may:
-remove the loop, i.e. close the socket on server side, after sending back the message to client
-make a similar loop on the client side (continuously write and read messages to/from server)